# WKWebView broken scroll/selection when contenteditable="true"

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

When I load [local html](https://github.com/halfred888/wktest/blob/master/wktest/test.html) in WKWebView with `<body contenteditable="true">` [I need to scroll downwards when selecting range over keyboard](https://github.com/halfred888/wktest/blob/master/select.gif).

In order to do that I have added some observers for keyboardWillShowOrHide and keyboardWillShowOrHide to adjust the `scrollView.contentInset` and `scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets`. That works fine and as expected.

The problem now I'm experiencing is [flickering](https://github.com/halfred888/wktest/blob/master/flicker.gif) and [broken scroll](https://github.com/halfred888/wktest/blob/master/scroll.gif) while selecting range of text.

The flickering and broken scroll can be fixed by adding to html `<body contenteditable="true" style="overflow:hidden;">` But that breaks the initial [scroll downwards when selecting range over keyboard](https://github.com/halfred888/wktest/blob/master/select.gif).

Any hints/help would be appreciated.

[Here is a link to test projects git](https://github.com/halfred888/wktest)